# osmdroid setUserAgentValue Cannot resolve Method

Tags: android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have used this tutorial: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library

But the Map doesn't show and I get an error: setUserAgentValue Cannot resolve Method

In this Line:

```
org.osmdroid.tileprovider.constants.OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
```

I have imported this:

```
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
```

And in my Gradle this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

osmdroid4.3 is out of date, and was not supporting setUserAgent.

Upgrade to the latest version, replace with:

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.4.1:release@aar'
```